# App crash when run in my device using Xcode

Tags: xcode, multithreading, dyld

any app in Xcode When i try to run it in my device it will crash without errors but it is working in the simulator fine
Even i tried to run An Empty App without code but still the same problem
and this is what is appear to me
i deleted the xcode and reinstalled it again but it is the same problem

Thread 1: signal SIGCONT 
And The Threat called 0 dyld_start

in the output result is the error (lldb)

```
dyld`_dyld_start:
->  0x1025fd1d8 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
0x1025fd1dc <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x1025fd1e0 <+8>:   mov    x0, #0x0
0x1025fd1e4 <+12>:  mov    x1, #0x0
0x1025fd1e8 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x1025fd1ec <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
0x1025fd1f0 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
0x1025fd1f4 <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x1025fd1f8 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #0x8]
0x1025fd1fc <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
0x1025fd200 <+40>:  adrp   x4, -1
0x1025fd204 <+44>:  add    x4, x4, #0x0              ; =0x0 
0x1025fd208 <+48>:  adrp   x3, 61
0x1025fd20c <+52>:  ldr    x3, [x3, #0x470]
0x1025fd210 <+56>:  sub    x3, x4, x3
0x1025fd214 <+60>:  mov    x5, sp
0x1025fd218 <+64>:  bl     0x1025fd260               ; dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
0x1025fd21c <+68>:  mov    x16, x0
0x1025fd220 <+72>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x1025fd224 <+76>:  cmp    x1, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
0x1025fd228 <+80>:  b.ne   0x1025fd234               ; <+92>
0x1025fd22c <+84>:  add    sp, x28, #0x8             ; =0x8 
0x1025fd230 <+88>:  br     x16
0x1025fd234 <+92>:  mov    x30, x1
0x1025fd238 <+96>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #0x8]
0x1025fd23c <+100>: add    x1, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
0x1025fd240 <+104>: add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x1025fd244 <+108>: add    x2, x2, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x1025fd248 <+112>: mov    x3, x2
0x1025fd24c <+116>: ldr    x4, [x3]
0x1025fd250 <+120>: add    x3, x3, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x1025fd254 <+124>: cmp    x4, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
0x1025fd258 <+128>: b.ne   0x1025fd24c               ; <+116>
0x1025fd25c <+132>: br     x16
```

And The Threat called 0 dyld_start

Comment: have you registered the device in the apple developer portal? i guess you must of done. no output in console? is the device running at least the min ios version that your app supports?

Comment: i used Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox) for local notifications and the ios target in xcode is ios 10 and my ios is 11.3.1 
the out put is (lldb) only